# iOS: How to limit the width of CGRectMake

Tags: ios, objective-c, frame, cgrectmake

I am making a very simple app, that has an UIButton and an UIImageView. Every time the user taps the button the image width increases by 5. My question is, how can I limit the width of the image? lets say, if it reaches 90 then prevent the image from increasing its width. What do I need to implement in my code?

Here is my code:

File.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
     IBOutlet UIButton *buttonOne;
     IBOutlet UIImageView *imageOne;
}

-(IBAction)buttonOne:(id)sender;

@end
```

File.m

```
@implementation ViewController

-(IBAction)buttonOne:(id)sender{

imageOne.frame = CGRectMake(100, 31, imageOne.frame.size.width + 5, 28);

}

@end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
imageOne.frame = CGRectMake(100, 31, MIN(90, imageOne.frame.size.width + 5), 28);
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple `if` statement:

```
CGFloat width = imageOne.frame.size.width;
if (width <= 85) {
    width += 5;
}
imageOne.frame = CGRectMake(100, 31, width, 28);
```

Answer (score 1):

To make it so that if it is greater or equal to 90 than it will stay at 90 and not get any bigger.

```
CGFloat width = imageOne.frame.size.width;
if (width >= 90) {
    width -= (width - 90);
}
imageOne.frame = CGRectMake(100, 31, width, 28);
```